# How to create a mutable string class that can be used as an actual string?

Tags: python, string, mutable

I want to create a python class that represents a string, but can be modified efficiently.
I thought about implementing a treelike data structure, but I don't know how to make it behave like a string, such that it can be used in all kind of string functions, for instance in regular expressions.

Of course one could construct a string from the data structure each time it is needed, but that isn't very efficient, and wastes the efficiency of the data structure.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a note, functions from the standard ``re`` module require the string to be hashable, which will conflict with the mutability requirement. Otherwise perhaps you may want to look at ``numpy`` arrays of characters.

Comment: @Bogdan the library I linked to below claims it works with `re`, too.

Comment: @Bogdan Thanks for the note! Can you explain (or point to an explanation) why this is needed?

Comment: @Ecir, I have just installed it to try it out, and it does not work with ``re``. Perhaps the caching was added later than this library was last updated.

Comment: @Bogdan ah, too bad. Thanks for the info, though!

Comment: @Chiel92: well, all the ``re`` functions try to cache the regular expression so they do not have to compile it every time. And caching, in turn, calls ``hash``, and ``__hash__`` protocol requires (naturally) that the object is immutable. See [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) for details.

Comment: @Bogdan But I suppose that the hashing is only needed for the pattern, not for the string which is searched through.

Comment: Oh, my bad then. In this case Ecir's solution sounds fine.

Answer (score 3):

I think one needs to implement both "sequence" and "buffer" Python protocols, which are only available from C. There is one library I know about which does this, though it's a bit dated:

https://code.google.com/p/gapbuffer/

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Too bad gapbuffer is C only